# Hibernate @Formula is not supporting query contains 'CAST() as int' function

Tags: java, hibernate

Following is the one of property of ExecutionHistory class, which value is fetched from 
@Formula using JPA/Hibernate from exectution_history table,

```
@Formula("(SELECT SUM(dividend) || '/' || SUM(divisor) " +
"FROM (SELECT CAST(substr(sr.result, 1, position('/' in sr.result)-1 ) AS int) AS dividend ," +
"CAST(substr(sr.result, position('/' in sr.result)+1 ) AS int) AS divisor " +
"FROM suite_results as sr WHERE sr.execution_history=id) AS division)")
private String result;
```

When I tried to get instance of ExecutionHistory class, I found that above formula query
is converted by JPA/Hibernate like this:

```
select executionh0_.id as id7_1_, executionh0_.execution_plan as execution3_7_1_, executionh0_.start_time as start2_7_1_, 
(SELECT SUM(sr.duration) FROM suite_results as sr WHERE sr.execution_history=executionh0_.id) as formula0_1_, 
(SELECT SUM(executionh0_.dividend) || '/' || SUM(executionh0_.divisor) FROM 
(SELECT CAST(substr(sr.result, 1, position('/' in sr.result)-1 ) AS executionh0_.int) AS executionh0_.dividend , 
CAST(substr(sr.result, position('/' in sr.result)+1 ) AS executionh0_.int) AS executionh0_.divisor 
FROM suite_results as sr WHERE sr.execution_history=executionh0_.id) AS executionh0_.division) as 
formula1_1_, executionp1_.id as id6_0_, executionp1_.build_number as 
build2_6_0_, executionp1_.name as name6_0_, executionp1_.owner as owner6_0_, executionp1_.sut as sut6_0_, 
executionp1_.wait_for_page_to_load as wait6_6_0_ from execution_history executionh0_ 
left outer join execution_plans executionp1_ on executionh0_.execution_plan=executionp1_.id where executionh0_.id=?
```

So the problem is that, here formula query contains "CAST() AS int", but during query conversion by Hibernate, it puts unnecessary table reference and execute it as "CAST() AS executionh0_.int"  so it giving sql grammer exeception while execution.

I've no idea about how to avoid this problem, Can anybody help me in this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It's an old question, but I'll post an answer anyway.

If you are using a SQL Server database, you can add double quotes around the type you are casting.
Something like this:

```
@Formula("CAST(FLOOR(CAST( dat_criacao AS \"float\")) AS \"datetime\")")
```

Comment: Thanks! I want to add that, if you are using XML mapping instead of Annotations, you need to use simple quotes and no slashes, like this: 

<property formula='(CAST(FLOOR(CAST( dat_criacao AS "float")) AS "datetime"))'

Answer (score 0):

Don't know which database you're using, but in SQL Server you should use CONVERT rather than CAST in you Hibernate queries.